# How can override default_get in odoo9?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I want to override `default_get` in odoo9 and My code

```py
class account_payment(models.Model):
_inherit = "account.payment"

    @api.model
    def default_get(self, fields):
        #print 'PRINT1',MAP_INVOICE_TYPE_PARTNER_TYPE
        rec = super(account_payment, self).default_get(fields)
        invoice_defaults = self.resolve_2many_commands('invoice_ids', rec.get('invoice_ids'))
        if invoice_defaults and len(invoice_defaults) == 1:
            invoice = invoice_defaults[0]
            rec['communication'] = invoice['reference'] or invoice['name'] or invoice['number']
            rec['currency_id'] = invoice['currency_id'][0]
            rec['payment_type'] = invoice['type'] in ('out_invoice', 'in_refund', 'sponsor_invoice',) and 'inbound' or 'outbound'  # modified for charity
            rec['partner_type'] = MAP_INVOICE_TYPE_PARTNER_TYPE[invoice['type']]
            rec['partner_id'] = invoice['partner_id'][0]
            rec['amount'] = invoice['residual']
        return rec
```

but when I click create it shows an error message, that point the inherited class first then calling base class, how is that possible?  Please help.

Error message:

> File "/opt/odoo_v9_charity/server/addons/web_charity/models/account_payment.py", line 87, in default_get
>         rec = super(account_payment_charity, self).default_get(fields)
>       File "/opt/odoo_v9_charity/server/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
>         return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       File "/opt/odoo_v9_charity/server/openerp/addons/account/models/account_payment.py", line 257, in default_get
>         rec['partner_type'] = MAP_INVOICE_TYPE_PARTNER_TYPE[invoice['type']]
>       KeyError: u'sponsor_out_invoice'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dict/map `MAP_INVOICE_TYPE_PARTNER_TYPE` simply does not have the key `'sponsor_out_invoice'`. Maybe you should add it.